# Order of operation for **

Tags: python

I want to know why does the following happen. 
The code below evaluates right side `1**3` first then `2**1`

```
2**1**3 has the value of 2
```

However, for the below code left side `7//3` is evaluated first then `2*3`. Finally `1+6-1=6`.

```
1+7//3*3-1 has the value of 6
```

Comment: Hi, I understand that python eval its from left to right but I dun understand why python evaluate power differently.

Comment: @Ibragile I understand in term of math but in terms of python normally evaluate from left to right.

Comment: In order to make sense mathematically, exponentiation needs to be evaluated right-to-left.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at the [documentation of operator precedence](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence).  Although multiplication `*` and floor division `//` have the same precedence, take note of this part:

> Operators in the same box group left to right (except for exponentiation, which groups from right to left).

For the convention of 2<sup>1<sup>3</sup></sup> being evaluated right-associative, see cross-site dupe on the math stackexchange site [What is the order when doing x<sup>y<sup>z</sup></sup> and why?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1633790/14118)

To put it simply, since the left-associative version (x<sup>y</sup>)<sup>z</sup> would just equal x<sup>y*z</sup>, it's not useful to have another (worse) notation for the same thing, so exponentiation should be right associative.

Answer (score 3):

Almost *all* operators in Python (that share the same precedence) have left-to-right associativity. For example:

```
1 / 2 / 3   ≡   (1 / 2) / 3
```

One exception is the exponent operator which is right-to-left associativity:

```
2 ** 3 ** 4   ≡   2 ** (3 ** 4)
```

That's just the way the [language is defined](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence), matching mathematical notation where `abc ≡ a(bc)`.

If it were  `(ab)c`, that would just be `abc`.

Comment: I guess so. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Per [Operator Precedence](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence), the operator is right associative:  `a**b**c**d == a**(b**(c**d))`.

So, if you do this:

```
a,b,c,d = 2,3,5,7
a**b**c**d == a**(b**(c**d))
```

you should get true after a looooong time.

Answer (score 0):

The Exponent operator in python has a **Right** to **Left** precedence. That is out of all the occurrences in an expression the calculation will be done from Rightmost to Leftmost. The exponent operator is an exception among all the other operators as most of them follow a Left to Right associativity rule.

```
2**1**3 = 2
```

The expression

```
1+7//3*3-1
```

It is a simple case of Left to Right associativity. As **//** and * operator share the same precedence, Associativity(one is the Left) is taken into account.

Answer (score 0):

This is just how math typically works

2<sup>1<sup>3</sup></sup>

This is the same as the first expression you used.  To evaluate this with math, you'd work your way down, so 1<sup>3</sup>=1 and then 2<sup>1</sup> which equals 2.

Answer (score 0):

You can make sense of this just by thinking about the classic PEMDAS (or Please Excuse My Dear Aunt Sally) order of operations from mathematics. In your first one, `2**1**3` is equivalent to [image: formula], which is really read as [image: formula2]. Looking at it this way, you see that you do parenthesis (P) first (the `1**3`).

In the second one, `1+7//3*3-1 == 6` you have to note that the MD and AS of PEMDAS are actually done in order of whichever comes first reading from left-to-right. It's simply a fault of language that we have to write one letter before another (that is, we could write this as PEDMAS and it still be correct if we treat the D and M appropriately).

All that to say, Python is treating the math exactly the same way as we should even if this were written with pen and paper.